# Something wrong with the debugger in php (wrong bug lines, etc)

Tags: php, ubuntu

I think my server is haunted. I have this running on all scripts

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('html_errors', 0);
```

And I got an error in script `this.php`

```
Notice: Undefined index: filter in /(...)/this.php on line 217
```

Line 217 is not even from the called function... it's an empty line with nothing in it.

Sometimes I run some `echo`s in a perfect logical flow condition (in the sense that it HAD to run) and they echo nothing. Sometimes they do. I just commented mysqliquery lines and for some reason they continue to query and save things to the database. I'm using ubuntu's native `Connect to server` functionality but also tried this in filezilla and it keeps happening. I know the files are saving. But the scripts doesn't seem to be reacting. It's the first time I'm facing such a thing and it's really completely odd. I've tried thinking of everything but got nothing satisfying. Duplicate/similar functions names, wrong directives, includes, file buffers, but it all seems inside reasonable criteria. I don't know what might be wrong. Does anyone know what might be happening?

**Scenario:**

Running php through nodejs. Worked flawlessly until now.

PHP function called: `first()` in script `one.php`

one.php:

```
include("this.php")

function first(){
    echo "This is echoed. This script works. I can remove and update this and line and it works well with the debugger"
    second(); //second is in this.php
}
```

this.php:

```
functions second(){
     echo "THIS GETS NO ECHO, IT'S THE FIRST LINE IN SECOND()"

     global $mysqli;

     //filter as index is in line 183, 168, 170, 185, 190.
     //line 217 is completely out of this function bounds.

     $query = "some query"

     $mysqli->query($query); //I commented this. Still gets query...
}
```

I really really don't understand what might be happening. I checked and double checked and can only assume it's a problem of the file buffer or something because the code seems correct to me...

EDIT:

I just COMPLETELY removed `second()` from this.php. The code runs as if nothing happened... wtf... I ran `cat this.php` in the terminal. The code seems up to date. It IS reaching the server...

Comment: I never see this problem. which version of PHP do you have ? when you have the error `Notice: undefined index`, does this error exist on another line ?

Comment: @SatenderK I updated the answer

Comment: @mmm I updated the answer

Comment: change it **include(this.php)** to **include('this.php')**

Comment: @Fane is it working now

Comment: @SatenderK obviously I already had it between commas, I just forgot to put it here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I... I had two different scripts with the same name in different folders... I hate myself...

Comment: No need to hate yourself... at least you figured it out.